# Term for someone very good at dodging being blamed?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

What do you call someone who is very good at dodging responsibility for his mistakes?

Comment: An elected official; a politician.

Comment: You can say "*That guy is [made of] **teflon***".

Comment: You can call them ***slippery***, though that possibly connotes more dishonesty than you are looking for here.

Comment: Yeah, "Teflon" is a common term (and often applied to politicians).

Comment: Didn't the saying "Teflon president" come into vogue during Reagan's administration?

Comment: @DanBron, with the ODO definition, *teflon* is a worthy answer and probably the best one.

Comment: @rhetorician: Yes, the context of the term "Teflon President" was that when critics tried to link President Reagan to unsuccessful policies or shady activities within his administration or to disastrous events outside it, they could never make anything "stick." Most notably, during the Iran/Contra investigations, he presented himself as being out of touch with the nitty-gritty details of pro-Contra activity at the National Security Agency—or for that matter, the activities of staffers there in broad outline—and most of the U.S. public found him believable.

Comment: @Dan Bron, why don't make this an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One relevant term that has been in vogue for several decades in politics is **deniability**, as in "We suspect that Governor X masterminded the highway on-ramp closures to punish Mayor Y for not endorsing him in the last election; but Governor X is insulated from involvement in the closure order by several layers of underlings, so from a legal perspective he still has strong deniability."

Another common idiomatic term (which Dan Bron and Hot Licks note in comments above) is **Teflon**, referring to the no-stick surface used on cookware and utensils to make them easy to clean. As rhetorician notes in a comment above, the term *Teflon* initially gained political prominence in connection with President Reagan, who seemed to retain his personal popularity even when his administration's policies came under fire and when various members of his administration got into legal trouble. Reagan's political adversaries sometimes called him "the Teflon President" because they couldn't make any of the fallout from these setbacks and scandals stick to him.

An even older expression of a similar notion is contained in the schoolyard taunt, "I'm rubber and you're glue; whatever you say bounces off me and sticks on you." The rubber kid thus evades the barbs and accusations that are flying about, while the glue kid soon wears a lead cloak of adhering calumnies. This, in a nutshell, is how our adult political process still works in the United States.

Answer (score 3):

Good question!  I can't think of a single word, but an old saying is:

**"He/She always comes out smelling like a rose."**

Answer (score 2):

I have heard references to "The Artful Dodger" character from Oliver Twist used effectively in this context. 
i.e. "That boy can get out of anything, he's an Artful Dodger"

other options could be slick, sly, wily, elusive, foxy, cunning, crafty, cagey, shrewd, subtle...

Answer (score 0):

A good word for someone who dodges responsibility is a **shirker**. Other possibilities: dead-beat, avoider, goldbrick.

Comment: That's avoiding work -- different from avoiding blame.

Comment: Well, the questioner asked about "responsibility" (not "blame"), and the definition according to dictionary.com is "a person who evades work, duty, responsibility, etc." But perhaps a compound noun like responsibility-shirker would make it clearer?

Comment: I think people may be voting down my answer without actually knowing or taking a moment to look up the definition of "shirker," which makes me sad. I encourage the questioner to look "shirker" up in a dictionary and decide for herself/himself. TY! :)

Comment: I just checked several online dictionaries.  The definition is generally "one who deliberately avoids work or duty".  Implies nothing about responsibility, save from the indirect point that the avoided work/duty *may* involve responsibility.

Comment: dictionary.com: 
to evade (work, duty, responsibility, etc.). thefreedictionary.com: To avoid or neglect (a duty or responsibility). oxforddictionaries.com: Avoid or neglect (a duty or responsibility): Merriam-Webster: to avoid doing something that you are supposed to do

Comment: Hot Licks, I think you're wrong on this. I don't know what sites you used, but most explicitly mention the word "responsibility," and Merriam-Webster and Cambridge at least imply it. Also, you seem to be suggesting that "duty" is a synonym for "work", when it's much closer in meaning to "responsibility." In fact, Oxford defines "duty" as "responsibility." So if you agree that "shirk" means "avoiding duty," you've implicitly conceded the argument, unless you feel Oxford has defined "duty" incorrectly.